# parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file which contains multiple declarations like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <node>
  <element1>Stefan</element1>
  <element2>42</element2>
  <element3>Shirt</element3>
  <element4>3000</element4>  
</node>
</root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <node>
  <element1>Damon</element1>
  <element2>32</element2>
  <element3>Jeans</element3>
  <element4>4000</element4>  
</node>
</root>
```

when i tried to load the xml with

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("testdoc.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

then it gives me the following error

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): testdoc.xml:11: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\crea\services\testxml.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in C:\xampp\htdocs\crea\services\testxml.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\crea\services\testxml.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): testdoc.xml:12: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\crea\services\testxml.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <root> in C:\xampp\htdocs\crea\services\testxml.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\crea\services\testxml.php on line 3
Error: Cannot create object
```

please let me know how to parse this xml or how to split it into no of xml files so that i can read. The file size is around 1 gb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

needs to be removed. Only 1 xml declaration is a allowed in any file and it must be the first line.

Strictly speaking, you also need to have a single root element (though i've seen lenient parsers). Just wrap the contents with a pseudo tag, such that your file would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metaroot><!-- synthetic unique root, no semantics attached -->
    <root>
        <!-- ... -->
    </root>
    <root>
        <!-- ... -->
    </root>

    <!-- ... -->
</metaroot>
```

Solution for (very) large files:

Use `sed` to eliminate offending xml declarations and `printf` to add a single xml declaration plus a unique root element. A sequence of bash commands follows:

```
  printf "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<metaroot>\n" >out.xml
  sed '/<\?xml /d' in.xml >>out.xml
  printf "\n</metaroot>\n" >>out.xml
```

`in.xml` denotes your original file,`out.xml` the purged result.

`printf` prints a single xml declaration and the opening/closing tags.
`sed` is a tool to edit a file line by line performing actions contingent on regex pattern matches. The pattern to match is the start of the xml declaration (`<\? xml`), the action to perform is to delete that line.

Notes:

- the backslashes in the commands escape symbols with special semantics at the position where they occur.
- `sed` is available for windows/macos too.

### Alternate solution

Another option is to split the file into individual well-formed files (taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274345):

```
csplit -z -f 'temp' -b 'out%03d.xml' in.xml '/<\?xml /' {*}
```

which produces files named `out000.xml`, `out001.xml`, ...
You should know at least the magnitude of the number of individual files that have been processed into your input file to be safe with the autonumbering ( though you could of course take the byte number of the input file as the magnitude, using `-b 'out%09d.xml'` in the above command).

Comment: Sir the file is about 1 GB and it contains multiple declarations and the above is just the sample of its structure.

Comment: Do you have control over the generation of the file? Apparently it consists of concatenated well-formed xml files - they could be preprocessd by stripping their first line.

Comment: I understand sir, tell me how i implement these changes in that xml file which consists of 1 gb data

Comment: And that file is coming from a data feed server so i cant control the generation of xml

Comment: use `printf` and `sed` to postprocess your file (deleting the offending xml declarations and adding the `metaroot` element. cli sample added to answer.

Comment: I imagine the people producing the data feed would want to know that it is unusable. Otherwise why would they produce it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid XML. You will need to use string functions to split it - or to be more exact to read it part by part.

```
$xmlDeclaration = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

$file = new SplFileObject($filename, 'r');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);
$buffer = '';
foreach ($file as $line) {
  if (FALSE === strpos($line, $xmlDeclaration)) {
    $buffer .= $line; 
  } else {
    outputBuffer($buffer);
    $buffer = $line;
  }
}
outputBuffer($buffer);

function outputBuffer($buffer) {
  if (!empty($buffer)) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXml($buffer);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//element1)'), "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Stefan
Damon
```